# Text getting blurred after scaling in css

Tags: html, css

I am using scale transform to zoom a div in html but the text within is getting blurred. Is there any way I can make the text clear as original

```css
@keyframes scaleText {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(2, 2);
  }
}

#para1Six {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  z-index: 2;
}
#wrapper 
{
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation-name: scaleText;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="envelope open">
    <div class="flap front"></div>
    <div class="flap top"></div>
    <div class="letter">
      <p id="para1Six">
        Hello World
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please attach your html code.To know whether yo have added your text inside span or p stuffs.

Comment: I have added it inside p

Answer (score 0):

You can trnasform your text without scale.

Use `font-size` for text and `transform:scale()` for div separately.

Comment: #para1Six is inside the div id="wrapper" and I am scaling the div so the text is also getting scaled

Comment: which div do you scale? Can you write the class?

Comment: I scale <div id="wrapper">

Comment: I just noticed, actually the text is not getting blurred, the div is getting blurred

Comment: there is only text in example and it is not blurred. There is no problem, isn't it?